# Как правильно использовать Monitor.Wait и Pulse?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите, как выполняется данный код:

```
lock (locker) {
    while (x == 0) {
        if (y > 0) {
            Monitor.Pulse(locker);
            break;
        }
        Monitor.Wait(locker);
    }

    // что-то еще делаем
}
```

Задача - синхронизация потоков.

Допустим есть очередь, в которую один поток пишет, другой из нее читает. Вот пока эта очередь пуста, поток "читатель" должен ждать пока не появятся данные.

Я хочу понять для себя, что происходит при вызове `Monitor.Wait` и  `Monitor.Pulse`. Т.е. когда очередь пуста, мы вызываем `Monitor.Wait`, поток переходит в режим ожидания, пока ресурс не освободиться (пока не будет данных для чтения), т.е. пока поток "писатель" не запишет данные и не предупредит следующий поток что ресурс скоро освободится командой `Monitor.Pulse`.

Вопрос в следующем, когда поток выходит из состояния - `Monitor.Wait`, т.е. в цикле `while (x == 0)` `x` - изменится, будет ли еще раз проверяться условие `if (y > 0)` либо же будет исполняться следующий после цикла код?

Comment: Для чего тут вообще мониторы, когда код и так в lock? Что вы этим кодом сделать то хотите?

Comment: В этом коде нет ни циклов, ни запуска новых потоков, поэтому сказать что либо невозможно.

Comment: @tym32167 постарался описать более подробно. в челом хочу понять, что происходит с потоком при вызове `Monitor.Wait` и при выходе из состояния ожидания.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Когда вы вызовите [Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ateab679(v=vs.110).aspx), то ваш поток освободит блокирующий объект `locker` и **заблокирует текущий поток**. Цикл не завершится. 
Функция Wait в *потоке1* завершится только тогда, кода другой поток(*поток2*) вызовет функцию [Pulse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx)(или PulseAll) для этого объекта и **освободит блокирующий объект**. Пока *поток2* не освободит объект блокировки, функция `Wait` в *потоке1* не завершится. 
Стоит отметить, что функции Wait, Pulse, PulseAll **не могут быть вызваны, если текущий поток не является владельцем блокировки**, поэтому обертка их в `lock(locker)` обязательна. В противном случае, при вызове этих методов возникнет исключение [SynchronizationLockException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.synchronizationlockexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ниже поясняющий пример работы функций

```
public static void Main()
{
            object locker = new object();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        lock (locker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending a signal...");                
            Monitor.Pulse(locker);
            Console.WriteLine("The signal was sent");
            x = 1;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep in lock finished");
        }
    });


    lock (locker)
    {
        while (x == 0)
        {
            if (y > 0)
            {
                Monitor.Pulse(locker);
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Wait...");
            Monitor.Wait(locker);
            Console.WriteLine("Wait finished");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("While finished");
    }
}
```

Вывод программы будет следующий:

> Wait... 
>   Sending a signal... 
>   The signal was sent 
>   Sleep in lock finished 
>   Wait finished 
>   While finished

**Ответ на вопрос:** Если `Wait` завершится, условие цикла при `x !=0` будет false, соответственно цикл завершится и будет выполнятся код после цикла. Повторной проверки `y>0` внутри цикла в этом случае невозможна!

Comment: а почему Monitor.Pulse именно в той строчке, где вы его написали? нет ли риска, что сразу после пульса другой поток может перехватить управление?